# How to configure the double click behavior in an X terminal?

Tags: mouse, xterm

Under different Unix/Linux systems I've observed different double click behavior in X terminal applications (e.g. xterm).

Sometimes a double click selects everything left and right until the next non-alphabetic character (e.g. it selects the word under the cursor).

Sometimes everything until the next blank/eol is selected (e.g. full paths under the cursor are selected).

How can I configure the double click behavior - say - in xterm (because it is available on most systems)?

Currently, I find the 2nd mode more convenient for most use cases.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You do it with X resources.  I have a file, `.Xresources`, that contains these xterm-related resources:

```
XTerm*VT100.cutNewLine: false
XTerm*VT100.cutToBeginningOfLine: false
XTerm*VT100.charClass: 33:48,35:48,37:48,42:48,45-47:48,64:48,95:48,126:48
```

In my `.xinitrc` file, I have some line that merge in those resources:

```
if [ -f $userresources ]; then
    /usr/X11/bin/xrdb -merge $userresources
fi
```

Those lines make xterm double-clicks and triple-clicks do what I like:

Double-click considers a "word" to include slash (/), dot (.), asterisk (*) and some other non-alphanumeric characters.  That's the "charClass" resource.  I had to do some tedious fiddling with that charClass to get it to do what I want.  That mostly lets you double-click on URLs and fully- or partially-qualified paths to highlight them.

The other two lines make triple-click start from the word under the mouse, and go to the end of the line, but not include any new-line.  That way, you can triple click on a command you just executed, paste it in another window, and because it has no new-line, you can edit it before running it in the other window.

The Arch Wiki has an [article on X resources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources), including a section on xterm resources, but those xterm resources aren't complete.

Comment: Wikis can be useful, but the place to consult for xterm resources is its [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html).

Comment: Or use `XTerm*VT100.charClass: 0-32:0,33-65535:1`. Double-click will then consider a "word" to be any sequence of symbols excluding whitespace (and control characters).

Comment: The whitespace rule is no good if you want to get what's inside quotes, in a json oneliner for instance. But I guess it depends on the usage you have. The provided snippet in this answer is perfect for me.

Comment: You've got a mistake: `cutNewLine` -> `cutNewline`. Maybe that was introduced in newer versions.

Comment: And `onNClicks: regex` seems at least more readable.

Answer (score 9):

`xterm` has several resource-settings related to double- and triple-clicking for selection (the manual page lists all of the relevant resources):

> [**`cutNewline`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:cutNewline) (class **`CutNewline`**)
>   If "false", triple clicking to select a line does not include
>   the *Newline* at the end of the line.  If "true", the *Newline* is
>   selected.  The default is "true".
>
> [**`cutToBeginningOfLine`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:cutToBeginningOfLine) (class **`CutToBeginningOfLine`**)
>   If "false", triple clicking to select a line selects only from
>   the current word forward.  If "true", the entire line is
>   selected.  The default is "true".
>
> [**`on2Clicks`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:on2Clicks) (class On2Clicks)
>   [**`on3Clicks`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:on3Clicks) (class On3Clicks)
>   Specify selection behavior in response to multiple mouse
>   clicks.  A single mouse click is always interpreted as
>   described in the [Selection Functions](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Selection-Functions) section (see [*POINTER
>   USAGE*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-POINTER-USAGE)).  Multiple mouse clicks (using the button which
>   activates the select-start action) are interpreted according to
>   the resource values of on2Clicks, etc.  The resource value can
>   be one of these:
>
> **`word`**
>   Select a "word" as determined by the [charClass](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:charClass) resource.
>   See the [CHARACTER CLASSES](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-CHARACTER-CLASSES) section.
>
> **`line`**
>   Select a line (counting wrapping).
>
> **`group`**
>   Select a group of adjacent lines (counting wrapping).  The
>   selection stops on a blank line, and does not extend outside
>   the current page.
>
> **`page`**
>   Select all visible lines, i.e., the page.
>
> **`all`**
>   Select all lines, i.e., including the saved lines.
>
> **`regex`**
>   Select a "word" as determined by the regular expression
>   which follows in the resource value.
>
> **`none`**
>   No selection action is associated with this resource.  Xterm
>   interprets it as the end of the list.  For example, you may
>   use it to disable triple (and higher) clicking by setting
>   on3Clicks to "none".
>
> The default values for **`on2Clicks`** and **`on3Clicks`** are **"word"** and
>   **"line"**, respectively.  There is no default value for **`on4Clicks`**
>   or **`on5Clicks`**, making those inactive.  On startup, **xterm**
>   determines the maximum number of clicks by the **`onXClicks`**
>   resource values which are set.

Comment: What the manual doesn't tell you: For some distributions, the default is not the documented default.  Setting an empty charClass resource restores the documented default.  Whatever you specify for charClass overwrites only the the entries you specify; unspecified entries are restored to the documented default.  At least, that's how it appears to work for me.

Comment: I've run into [a post](https://www.tummy.com/blogs/2006/07/15/xterm-regex-matching-for-cut-selection/) that suggest the following values: `xterm*on2Clicks:  regex [^/@ \n]+`, `xterm*on3Clicks:  regex [^ \n]+`, `xterm*on4Clicks:  regex [^#$]+`, `xterm*on5Clicks:  line`. Seems better and easier to understand than those in the accepted answer.

Comment: On second thought, for now I decided to get the best of both approaches (at the least the way I understand it now): 2 clicks for a word, 3 clicks for a WORD (in `vim`'s sense, `xterm*on3Clicks: regex [^ \n]+`), 4 clicks for copying commands from shell (from current word to the end of the line, `xterm*on4Clicks: line`, `xterm*cutNewline: false`, `xterm*cutToBeginningOfLine: false`), 5 click for whole lines (`xterm*on5Clicks: regex [^\n]+`).