# Double click in Cygwin not selecting dot at beginning of paths

Tags: terminal, mouse, cygwin

I'm having an issue on one of my Cygwin installs where double clicking does not select the dot at the beginning of paths.

Normally I get this behaviour when double clicking a path:

[image]

But on the install where I'm having this issue, I get this:

[image]

Notice that it's not strictly breaking at dots, since it selects ".txt" at the end.

It's also not related to the path being at the beginning of a line:

[image]

And while I'm generally just hitting this issue with paths, it's not really limited to paths. More generally, it fails while searching left of the click location for a selection breakpoint if it finds a dot left of a slash. The following selections are all from double clicks.

Double clicking in "test":
[image]

Double clicking in first instance of "string":
[image]

Double clicking in second instance of "string":
[image]

BUT if I double click in "Here", it will extend beyond the dot as well as the slash after it:

[image]

Maybe calling this a failure is inaccurate, but it's different from what I've experienced previously where a double click on a path would include the leading dot. So I'd like to make the double click behaviour match the first example at the top of my post where leading dots on paths are included.

I'm running:

```
cygwin 3.4.7
bash  5.2.15(3)-release (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
mintty 3.6.4 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
```

I did see [this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45925/how-to-configure-the-double-click-behavior-in-an-x-terminal) that seems to be related, but I'm not clear if it applies to Cygwin as well. I'm not familiar with Xresources and I don't see any of the files they're discussing on the PC where I'm having this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I just discovered that double clicking between the leading dot and the slash after it will select the whole path the way I want. So I guess being a little more precise with clicking location is one workaround this issue. But who's got time for that?!?

Comment: `mintty` is a Windows application, you may have more luck in a Windows Q&A site. It's mostly off topic here.

Comment: This has been annoying me as well since a while, so if you repost this, please share the link here.

Comment: The Window's menu has a section "Options" where there are some settings related to the selection, but nothing to control the inclusion of the dot or not.

Comment: @le_top As discussed in the comments below, this appears to be a bug (or at least changed behaviour) with mintty 3.6.4. So one option for now is to downgrade to 3.6.2.

Comment: @SSilk Downgrading to 3.6.2 indeed does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The same problem has been bothering me for months.

Thanks to the hint from Stephane, I tried replacing the mintty 3.6.4-1 with an older version 2.9.6-0 (the oldest one I could found with the cygwin installer v2.926), and the problem was resolved!

Comment: Recommend you file a bug about this UX regression with the `mintty` maintainers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm also running mintty 3..4 on my problem machine. On another machine that's working fine, I'm running mintty 3.6.2. So you may only need to roll back that far to fix this.

Comment: @J_H Thanks for the tip. I didn't search the mintty issues before posting this. I assumed I had just messed up a setting somewhere that dictates how text is selected. Turns out this is an open issue already with version 3.6.4: https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/1208

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed already in the mintty repository, for 3.6.5.